# Error when using ProtocolLibrary PacketAdapter()

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a Craftbukkit plugin that has a message in the player count list, Like HIVE-MC or Omega Realm. I am coding in Ecplise and using ProtocolLib v3.2.0 and Craftbukkit 1.7.2 R0.3. I am new to java and don't understand it much.  I do know that everything is imported.

So far, here are the imported methods, code, and the error

Methods:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.comphenix.protocol.PacketType;
import com.comphenix.protocol.ProtocolLibrary;
import com.comphenix.protocol.events.ListenerOptions;
import com.comphenix.protocol.events.ListenerPriority;
import com.comphenix.protocol.events.PacketAdapter;
import com.comphenix.protocol.wrappers.WrappedGameProfile;
```

Code:

```
    private List<WrappedGameProfile> message = new ArrayList<WrappedGameProfile>();

public void onEnable() {
    if(!new File(getDataFolder(),"RESET.FILE").exists()){
        try {
            getConfig().set("PCMessage",
                    Arrays.asList(new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"}));
            new File(getDataFolder(),"RESET.FILE").createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
    saveConfig();

    for (String str : getConfig().getStringList("PCMessage"))
        message.add(new WrappedGameProfile("1", str));



    ProtocolLibrary
    .getProtocolManager()
    .addPacketListener(
            new PacketAdapter(
                    this,ListenerPriority.NORMAL,
            Arrays.asList(new PacketType[] {PacketType.Status.Server.OUT_SERVER_INFO}),
            new ListenerOptions[] { ListenerOptions.ASYNC })); {

    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

> Cannot instantiate the type PacketAdapter

Answer (score 0):

As you will see in the [Javadocs](http://aadnk.github.io/ProtocolLib/Javadoc/com/comphenix/protocol/events/PacketAdapter.html) for PacketAdapeter, it is declared as:

```
public abstract class PacketAdapter implements PacketListener
```

`abstract` means the class is not a full class, and must be implemented as a full class or [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), it cannot be instantiated. You need to find a subclass of PacketAdapter, or make one yourself.

For more information, see the Java Tutorial for [Abstract Methods and Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).